# Spring boot Thymeleaf same instance passed between endpoints as @ModelAttribute

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, thymeleaf, endpoint

I have a question regarding Thymeleaf and Spring Boot. I'm creating a form wizard and I would like to have the same object passed between multiple controllers, so that the object (SimpleCharacter) stores each time the value from each page.

What I have right now is, that with each endpoint, I get a new object created that "forgets" what I wanted to store from the previous page. How can I achieve that to have the same instance of the object passed between endpoints and in the end fully completed object with fields from each previous endpoint?

```
private static final String CHARACTER = "character";

@GetMapping(value = "/new-char/01_race")
public String showCharWizRace(Model model) {
    CharacterDto character = new SimpleCharacter();
    model.addAttribute(CHARACTER, character);
    return "new-char/01_race";
}

@PostMapping(value = "/new-char/02_class")
public String showCharWizClass(Model model, @ModelAttribute CharacterDto character) {
    model.addAttribute(CHARACTER, character);
    model.addAttribute("classes", charClassService.findAll());
    return "new-char/02_class";
}

@PostMapping(value = "/new-char/03_attributes")
public String showCharWizAttributes(Model model, @ModelAttribute CharacterDto character) {
    model.addAttribute(CHARACTER, character);
    return "new-char/03_attributes";
}
```

Thank you very much for all valuable hints and help. I've searched the Web, but couldn't find anything useful to point me in the right direction.

EDIT: But if you make CharacterDto have more fields for example race, class, attributes and use each time only one page (one form) to provide one field, spring "forgets" the other property when opening the next form. For example: 1st page: race is set, 2nd page (no race field existing here) class is set but in this place the previously set race had been already forgotten.

CharacterDto fields, that should be filled step by step on each page:

```
private String race;
private String charClass;

private int strength;
private int endurance;
private int dexterity;
private int charisma;
private int intelligence;
private int perception;

private String name;
private String surname;
private String description;
private String title;
private String avatar;
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your character field are inside a spring form?
If yes, you also could to store your variable in a hidden field and pass this by **@RequestParam**.
Follow a example:

```
<input th:field="*{character}" name="character"/>
```

And in your controller method add a request parameter variable

```
showCharWizClass(@RequestParam(value = "character", required = false) String character, otherVariables){}
```

If it doesn't work, you also try to use something like a template strategy with session.
Putting your variable in a session scope, changing the variable with each request and removing it on last access.

Here a good link about access data from templates:
https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html

**UPDATE**
You need to combine Model and Session Attributes in your workflow pages.
In your controller add a SessionAttribute pointing to the DTO that is using, like this:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("character")
public class WizardController { ..
```

And when you have finished your flow, you can end session attributes this way.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/new-char/04_clear")
public String clearSession(SessionStatus sessionStatus) {
    sessionStatus.setComplete();
    return "new-char/04_clear";
}
```

If you look at my example code I add a new page to clean session and restart a form with a default DTO values.

Comment: hey, thank you very much, I've thought already about using hidden fields, but this solution doesn't seem so elegant for me... it sounds a bit like a hack, it's a pity that Spring cannot handle this itself, maybe I'll try with session scope

Comment: @Bloodlex I create a simple code, similar yours, using **ModelAttribute** that was working. Look at https://github.com/julianopacheco/springboot I think could help you.

Comment: I think could be a form config that may be missing. Here other good example: https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/
If you will running my code, start by http://localhost:8080/new-char/01_race page and go sailing. Let me know with you have success in your implementation.

Comment: I've taken a look into your code and it works because you only have one field which always exists on the same form. But if you make SimpleCharacter have more fields for example race, class, attributes and use each time only one page (one form) to provide one field, spring "forgets" the other property when opening the next form. For example: 1st page: race is set, 2nd page (no race field existing here) class is set but in this place the previously set race had been already forgotten :(

Comment: @Bloodlex I think I understand your problem. In fact spring lost the value between requests. So you need to combine Model and Session Attributes. Look at the code update I made available now.